# Sequence Convergence Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that if d is a number and x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ... is a sequence which converges to
the point c, then the sequence d · x<sub>1</sub>, d · x<sub>2</sub>, d · x<sub>3</sub>, ... converges to d · c.

According to my text, the statement that the point sequence p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, ... converges to the point x means that if S is an open interval containing x then there is a positive integer N such that if n is a positive integer and n ≥ N then p<sub>n</sub> ∈ S.

I realize this seems to be an alternative to the delta-epsilon definition, but I'm not terribly sure about analysis/topology.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $|dx_n-dc| = |d||x_n-c|$